# Как заставить дочерние блоки подстраивать высоту под родительский элемент, и не вылезать за вьюпорт?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Html код** (сетка достаточно сложная, поэтому приведу структуру в общем виде)

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="block1">dynamic content</div>
            ...
      <div class="blockn">dynamic content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Css**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.block1 {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.blockn {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

не могу добиться того, чтобы при наполнении контентом блоки block1...blockn подстраивали свою высоту и при переполнении начинали скроллиться. При этом мне нужно, чтобы вся страничка целиком вписывалась в видимую часть экрана и не прокручивалась ни при каких условиях. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил к **.flex-container** свойство **max-height: 100vh;**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.block1 {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.blockn {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="block1">dynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic content</div>
            ...
      <div class="blockn">dynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic contentdynamic content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```